# Can I view my site as a user who doesnt have font installed?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to see the look of my site when a user accesses it from a computer on which the fonts of my site aren't installed! Is it possible?

Comment: I'd suggest adding a little more detail.  Are you using web fonts to potentially provide them (in which case you get to deal with the awesomeness that is IE prefers one type and Firefox/Chrome another and hopefully you _don't_ have to deal with the awesomeness that is IE's behavior if the font's cache property isn't set right)

Comment: @Foon I think best solution for my problem is using IE! Thanks buddy! post it as solution if you want! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rename the font in your CSS so that your own computer cannot find it. This is the same as being on a computer where the font is not installed.

Comment: Well nice suggestion! Thank you! But using IE makes my work quiet simple! still thank you for you answer! it might help me later!